# Discord.js collecting button interaction for buttons attached to replies

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a Discord.js bot that lets users vote on the outcome of games. Users can vote for team1 or team2 by clicking one of the buttons that the /addGame slash command generates. Once you have voted for a winner, I'd like the users to be able to then vote for how many games it will take by clicking a button that is attached to the bot reply for which team they voted for:

[image]

Right now the error shown is the only one I'm getting. No errors in the console. This is the entire slash command function:

#### /addGame.js

```
imports...

const collectorMap = new Map();

// Function to create series buttons
function createSeriesButtons(series) {
    const buttons = [];

    for (let i = 2; i <= series; i++) {
        buttons.push(new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId(`button${i}`)
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
            .setEmoji(`${i}️⃣`)
        );
    }

    return buttons;
}


module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('addgame')
        .setDescription('Sets up a game for placing bets.')
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('team1')
                .setDescription('Team 1')
                .setRequired(true)
                .addChoices(
                    ...teams
                ))
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('team2')
                .setDescription('Team 2')
                .setRequired(true)
                .addChoices(
                   ...teams
                ))
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('series')
                .setDescription('Number of games')
                .setRequired(true)
                .addChoices(
                    { name: '1', value: '1'},
                    { name: '3', value: '3'},
                    { name: '5', value: '5'},
                )),
    async execute(interaction) {
        // Set up team information
        const teamList = await getTeams();
        const team1 = interaction.options.getString('team1');
        const team2 = interaction.options.getString('team2');
        const teamArray = [team1, team2];
        let teamMessage1 = '';
        let teamMessage2 = '';
        const team1Info = teamList.find(team => team.Name === teamArray[0]);
        const team2Info = teamList.find(team => team.Name === teamArray[1]);
        teamMessage1 = team1Info.Emoji + ' ' + team1Info.Name;
        teamMessage2 = team2Info.Name + ' ' + team2Info.Emoji;

        const series = interaction.options.getString('series');

        // Build buttons
        const team1Button = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('team1Button')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
            .setEmoji(team1Info.Emoji);

        const team2Button = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('team2Button')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
            .setEmoji(team2Info.Emoji);

        const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(team1Button, team2Button);

         const message2 = await client.channels.cache.get('1162487828417085650').send({
             content: teamMessage1 + ' vs ' + teamMessage2,
             components: [row],
         });

         await addGame(team1, team2, series, message2.id);

         // Send the message and add buttons
         await interaction.reply({content: 'Game posted.' + team1Info.Emoji + ' ' + team2Info.Emoji + ' : ' + message2.id, fetchReply: true});

         const collector = message2.createMessageComponentCollector({ componentType: ComponentType.Button, time: 172800000 });

         collectorMap.set(message2.id, collector);



         collector.on('collect', async i => {
            // Get the collector associated with the message using message ID
            const messageCollector = collectorMap.get(i.message.id);

            try {
        
                if (i.customId === 'team1Button' || i.customId === 'team2Button') {

                    const seriesButtons = createSeriesButtons(parseInt(series));
                    const seriesRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(...seriesButtons);
                    const team = await getTeamEmoji(i.message.id, i.customId);
    
                    await castVote(team.name, i.user.username, i.message.id).then(() => {
                        i.reply({ 
                            content: "Vote for " + team.emoji + " submitted.", 
                            components: [seriesRow],
                            ephemeral: true });
                    });

                } else if (i.customId.startsWith('button')) {
                    console.log('We got here');
                    // Handle series vote when series buttons are clicked
                    const seriesLength = i.customId.replace('button', ''); // Extract the series length from the customId
                    console.log(seriesLength);
                    try {
                        await seriesVote(seriesLength, i.user.username, i.message.id).then(() => {
                            i.reply({ 
                                content: `Vote for ${seriesLength} games submitted.`, 
                                ephemeral: true });
                        });
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error("Error submitting series vote:", error);
                        logError(error, i.message.id, i.user.username, 'Error submitting series vote');
                    }
                }

        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Button interaction error:", error);
            console.log("Interaction Object:", i);
            console.log("Button interaction user: ", i.user.username);
            console.log("Button interaction messageID: ", i.message.id);
            logError(error, i.message.id, i.user.username, 'Button interaction error: ' + i);
        }
        });
    },
};
```

However I believe where we are focused is right here:

```
collector.on('collect', async i => {
            // Get the collector associated with the message using message ID
            const messageCollector = collectorMap.get(i.message.id);

            try {
        
                if (i.customId === 'team1Button' || i.customId === 'team2Button') {

                    const seriesButtons = createSeriesButtons(parseInt(series));
                    const seriesRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(...seriesButtons);
                    const team = await getTeamEmoji(i.message.id, i.customId);
    
                    await castVote(team.name, i.user.username, i.message.id).then(() => {
                        i.reply({ 
                            content: "Vote for " + team.emoji + " submitted.", 
                            components: [seriesRow],
                            ephemeral: true });
                    });

                } else if (i.customId.startsWith('button')) {
                    console.log('We got here');
                    // Handle series vote when series buttons are clicked
                    const seriesLength = i.customId.replace('button', ''); // Extract the series length from the customId
                    console.log(seriesLength);
                    try {
                        await seriesVote(seriesLength, i.user.username, i.message.id).then(() => {
                            i.reply({ 
                                content: `Vote for ${seriesLength} games submitted.`, 
                                ephemeral: true });
                        });
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error("Error submitting series vote:", error);
                        logError(error, i.message.id, i.user.username, 'Error submitting series vote');
                    }
                }

        }
    ...
```

I think the problem may be with the collector? It's like the bot doesn't understand how to collect button interactions from buttons that are attached to replies. However, the bot doesn't have a problem collecting multiple votes for different games if you add several at a time using `/addGame`.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could skip the collector altogether, and just make use of the **interactionCreate** event listener, and then do a check for the interaction type as well as the custom Id, and then handle the data from there. Let me give an example:

```js
client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
    // Let's make an interaction reply with buttons like yours
    
    let pollButton1 = new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId("team1")
        .setLabel("Team 1")
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
    let pollButton2 = new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId("team2")
        .setLabel("Team 2")
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
    let row = new ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(pollButton1, pollButton2)

    await interaction.reply({
        content: "Feedback",
        components: [row],
    });

    if (!interaction.isButton() || (interaction.customId !== "team1" && interaction.customId !== "team2")) {
        return;
    }
    
    // Now you can handle the poll data

    let chosenTeam = interaction.customId;
    let voter = interaction.user.id;
}
```

That's just an example, you could do the same with your code and even improve that by encapsulating the logic in functions to make it neater.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I'll give it a try when I get off work.

Comment: Hey I know it has been a while but this works great for 1 set of buttons but I run into problems when there are multiple sets of buttons at 1 time. For example, if 3 games are concurrently being voted on.  Any idea how I could handle that?

Thank you for your answer though. It did solve the original question so I'm marking it as the correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm if you mean if there are multiple polls with similar buttons ids active, then you could discern which is which by finding out which message the buttons come from since each button is part of a message. To do this you can get the message id via `interaction.message.id`.